# Using MySQL + Google spreadsheet to enter posts in CMS

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, google-apps-script

I'm trying to build a CMS which can be updated either via the backend interface of the CMS itself (based on codeigniter) or through a google docs spreadsheet that syncs to the MySQL db.

Anyone know of any resources / existing scripts that could help accomplish this?

The mechanism should ideally accomplish the following:
Image:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yll7gakhq6y3mdq/Screenshot%202015-01-30%2021.03.00.png

Answer (score 0):

you have to develop this functionality using google spreadshet API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#updating_a_list_row